# Azure Function not working with serviceBusTrigger NodeJs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-servicebus-topics

I have been trying to put a message in azure service bus topic. My azure function test says that the message has been accepted(202). But there is no message on the subscription side, Could you please help me in this POC. Here is my code snippet. It's a sample that got generated from VS code, I am using serviceBusTrigger.

```
const { ServiceBusClient, ReceiveMode } = require("@azure/service-bus"); 
module.exports = async function(context, mySbMsg) {
    context.log('JavaScript ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message', mySbMsg);
    context.done();
};
```

Is there any way that I can check if the service bus topic is working as expected?

Comment: Where is the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a connection string and a binding associated with the code, Inorder to save the message to the queue, you need to have the Queue connection strings in the settings file. Follow the [`docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node),

```
{
    "bindings": [
        {
            "schedule": "0/15 * * * * *",
            "name": "myTimer",
            "runsOnStartup": true,
            "type": "timerTrigger",
            "direction": "in"
        },
        {
            "name": "outputSbQueue",
            "type": "serviceBus",
            "queueName": "testqueue",
            "connection": "MyServiceBusConnection",
            "direction": "out"
        }
    ],
    "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: I have added the connection string in appsettings.json on cloud. But one thing I am not able to get is, Do we have to create a queue for this type of process. As far as I know that Queues and Topics are the two ways of using ASB. Sorry, I am just getting started in this.

Comment: what do you already have ? did you create the queue?

Comment: No, till now I have created one topic and one subscription to it. Do we need queue in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So the thing was, I tried calling the function after pushing messages onto the topic. But the purpose of ServiceBusTriger is reverse. The function with this trigger processes the message when there is message on queue. There is no need to Call the function separately. Yeah, so basics, just create the function with your available topic and subscription, and then try putting message onto the topic. You can see the message in the log of the function.